# Confidence interval for exponential - is it the shortest possible?

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-function, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

The confidence interval for an exponential distribution is said to be:
$$\frac{2n\bar{x}}{\chi^2_{1-\alpha /2,2n}}<\frac{1}{\lambda}<\frac{2n\bar{x}}{\chi^2_{\alpha /2,2n}}$$
In general we aim to obtain the shortest confidence interval possible. How can we be sure that this interval is the shortest? The presence of $\chi^2_{1-\alpha /2,2n}$ and $\chi^2_{\alpha /2,2n}$ suggests that there is a kind of a symmetry in the confidence interval, however, the exponential distribution is not symmetric.

Is not it true that we should build the interval around the region where the likelihood function is the greatest? It would mean that if the CI is $[a,b]$, then $L(a)=L(b)$ (likelihood) as we would be trying to utilise the part of likelihood function with the highest values.

Therefore, my question is - **Is the CI presented at the beginning the shortest CI possible for exponential?**

Comment: Have you looked at wikipedias cite? https://books.google.com/books?id=mXP_UEiUo9wC&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q&f=true I don't think the principle of selecting the shortest interval is applied here or in general. This one is not the shortest possible because $\chi^2$ is not symmetric - unlike the normal.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, however, chi-square distribution is not symmetric, so I can't see how it can provide the shortest CI possible. Of course it provides a 95% CI, but how can it be the shortest?

Comment: Then, how could we potentially find the shortest one?

Comment: For unimodal distributions, find $a,b$ s.t. $f_X(a)=f_X(b)$ and $\mu_X([a,b])=1-\alpha$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, exactly, this is what I thought. Therefore, in the case of a sample of size k, these two conditions would have to be satisfied: $\int^b_a \frac{1}{2^{k}\Gamma(k)}x^{k-1}e^{-x/2}=0.95$ and  $\frac{1}{2^{k}\Gamma(k)}a^{k-1}e^{-a/2}= \frac{1}{2^{k}\Gamma(k)}b^{k-1}e^{-b/2}$. Is that true?

Comment: Ah no! In this case we would actually like to utilise the part of chi-square distribution where it has the lowest likelihood, so we would like to choose something like $\chi^2_{0.949...9,2n}$ and $\chi^2_{0.0...01,2n}$, because we are actually dividing by these values. Right?

Comment: The problem with your approach to choosing a confidence interval (the shortest one) is that it is not (monotonic) transformation invariant. The shortest interval for $\chi^2$ will not translate in the shortest one of its inverse. Simply cutting off equal parts on each side (what is done above) is stable under monotonic transformations, on the other hand.

Comment: @A.S. It's very clear now, thank you very much.

Comment: This is not to say that your approach/choice is "wrong" or that the usual approach is the one to always use. If you are reporting on the very EXACT variable you are interested in and nothing else, your approach can be apropos if computationally more involved. A variation of the "usual" approach is used in finance in the value-at-risk (VaR) statistic which has been discredited/shown to be a poor one, for example. But usually, it's the one used in the least for mathematical convenience.

Comment: @A.S. That is very interesting what you are saying. Also, I think that now I understand how it works. In the example I have given, for small sample (say of size $k$), the density function (convolution of $k$ exponential distributions) would have left tail thicker than the right one and so it would be "better" to move the CI a bit to the left. For greater values of $k$, tails would be quite similar and so using chi-square in a symmetrical manner would do the job more or less.

Comment: To show why your method (smallest interval) is unstable take a $U(0,1)$ and slightly progressively load it either towards $1$, or towards $0$ (maintain linear pdf for simplicity). Your method will yield $[\alpha,1]$ and $[0,1-\alpha]$ CI respectively - a dramatic, discontinous change for a tiny change in slope from positive to negative. "The usual" will yield a "stable" perturbation around $[\alpha/2,1-\alpha/2]$. Bigger point: the common statistics/tools must be adopted to the problem at hand and rarely is there a universal approach (though it might seem so in the beginner stats courses).